# $location.path("/abc") not working in particular functions

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I have two functions defined as example. First one is

```
   $scope.redir = function () {
   $location.path('/abc');
  };
```

and it redirects fine, but next snippet doesn't work for some reason

```
  $scope.signup = function() {
  var user = {...}
  return $http.post('/auth/signup', user);
  $location.path("/abc");
  console.log($location.path());
  };
```

It does post part very well, user is added to a db correctly, but redirect doesn't follow.
I've tried using $rootScope as adviced in few questions, but result is the same - button with signup() assigned does http.post and stops at "pushed" state with no redirect following.
Here's what I pass to Ctrl by the way

```
function($scope, $location, $http)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, functions tend to stop when they hit `return`. ;)

Did you mean this?

```
$http.post(...).success(function () {
    $location.path(...);
})
```

Comment: punched my head realizing silliness of my question.